# Ionic issue after installation

Tags: ionic-framework, syntax-error

I need some helps to solve problems with ionic on my mac. For every command I launch from terminal with ionic, I receive the same error as shown below.

For example even if I give command `ionic -v`, I receive this:

```
$ ionic -v
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/dist/index.js:24
        const [xcode, iosDeploy, iosSim,] = yield Promise.all([
              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic:8:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
```

I have checked the file `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/dist/index.js`, but all is fine. Even there's this parse error, I even tried with uninstall and reinstalled ionic without success. Can someone give me suggestions please?

Comment: Good i have solved! My nodejs version was too old ( 5.6.0 ) and i have seen that it doesn't works with ionic cli, so i have installed before nvm

curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.1/install.sh | bash

and then launch from terminal ->  nvm install v6.10.3 to have last stable node js version, now all works again!

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved this! My nodejs version was too old (5.6.0) and I have seen that it doesn't work with ionic cli, so I have installed before nvm

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.1/install.sh | bash
```

and then launch from terminal ->  nvm install v6.10.3 to have last stable node js version, now all works again!

Answer (score 1):

Just remove nodejs from your linux :

> sudo apt remove nodejs

And install the latest version :

> curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
>
> sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

This come from the [official website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/)

This did the trick for me, Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. But After re installed latest version (7) of node.js .
It is working Properly.

1st I did flowing command on Ubuntu.

> npm cache clean -f
>
> npm install npm -g

2nd

> curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash - sudo
> apt-get install -y nodejs

Try this.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, i have already done your 1st point without success, problem is the same.


i have npm version 4.5.0
and node version 5.6.0
cordova version 7.0.0

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, I am able to solve it using upgrading node using following command :

```
nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=node
```