# Ionic with AngularJS - SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to follow this tutorial:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/create-your-first-mobile-app-with-angularjs-and-ionic#toc-making-a-todo-app

and when I type `ionic -v` or just `ionic` it is giving me this error:

```
AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\dist\index.js:24
        const [xcode, iosDeploy, iosSim,] = yield Promise.all([
              ^

Io
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic:8:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
```

I have installed cordova and ionic globally: `npm install cordova ionic -g` and locally, but same outcome. I have also done `npm init`.

What is the reason for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Does ionic support Destructuring assignments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this github issue: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/11588

And this: [Ionic issue after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43879265/ionic-issue-after-installation)

It looks to be an issue with the newer version of ionic. Upgrading your NodeJs version should do the trick.

> You have to update NodeJS.
>   CLI 3 needs >= 6.x